# Validation and DB Update : Java Servlet

Tags: java, multithreading, validation, servlets

Let me provide the execution flow of my application first.

In the application, subscribers can enroll by providing their information and Credit Card Number. Based on information provided, the application returns Success/Failure response.

There is a check in the application that one CC number can only be used at fixed number of times. The application checks whether that count is exceeded. If yes then, returns failure response.

Technically, it is designed using J2EE architecture (servlet and JSP). Now, the check for CC usage count is placed well above the insertion logic. Hence, if CC limit is configured to 1 and 2 enrollment requests with same CC number come at the same time, both the subscribers get enrolled whereas ideally only one should have.

Can anyone help me on this issue? One probable solution is that to bring together both (check and insertion) the operations and wrap them in static synchronized block. However, that does not seem appropriate in this specific case as it disturbs the whole flow. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When you do the read store how many times the card has been used ( I'm assuming that is a column on your table )

When you do the update, restrict the update to only do the update if the column on the table is the same as the value you stored earlier.

If you update 1 row then you're on to a winner.

If your update doesn;t update 1 row, then the card has been used more than once.

Comment: Yes. That is indeed a column on the table. Consider the following steps: Current count is 0 and max count is 1
1. Thread-1 comes in, reads the count (0) and stores it somewhere.

2. Thread-2 comes in, reads the count, which is still 0 as Thread-1 isn't finished yet.

3. Thread-1 finishes the insertion, finds the value and previously stored values same (0) and hence, updates it to 1.

4. Thread-2 completes the insertion, finds the values different and hence, doesn't store.

However, in this case, both the threads go through, which should not happen.

Comment: Not quite - in the second case - when it doesn't store - you recognise that the insert hasn't worked and report it back to the user as an error. This doesn't really fully solve your problem though as you would probably want both threads to work if the max count was 2 ... maybe change the update statement to only do the update if the column on the table was less than the max count. I think that would suit you better - you wouldn't even need to do the first read ( unless the other parts of your code rely on that data )